# Serialization using boost library

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'm trying to use boost library to serialize std::map so that is possible to store it in a file. However I'm having so weird behaviours (i guess). So here is my code:

```
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

std::map<int,int> map = {{65,2}, {69,1}, {75,1} ,{77,1}, {82,1}, {84,2}, {89,2}};

void saveMapToFile(std::ofstream& f);

int main()
{
    std::ofstream f("test.txt", std::ios::binary);

    saveMapToFile(f);

    std::cout << "position: " << f.tellp() << std::endl;
}

void saveMapToFile(std::ofstream& f)
{
    std::cout << "position : " << f.tellp() << std::endl;

    boost::archive::text_oarchive oarch(f);

    std::cout << "position : " << f.tellp() << std::endl;

    oarch << map;

    std::cout << "position : " << f.tellp() << std::endl;
}
```

And here is the above code's output:

```
position : 0
position : 28
position : 75
position: 76
```

So can someone explain to me what is happening here? Why position after insterting map (in function) in different outside of it? I don't do any additional opperations, yet that pointer goes one byte further... Am I missing something? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would be making assumptions about the implementation of the archive format.

Archives write headers, and can write "trailers" (think XML archives).

The destructor of `oarch` wrote another byte, finishing the stream. It could be a sentinel, a checksum, a newline etc.

Comment: Yeah i understand that, but i don't understand why it is inconsistent. I mean i want to save other data after that map in a file and I have problem with that. Where should i execute that storing? If i save the other data in that function ```saveMapToFile()``` it starts from 75th byte and if i do it outside it goes on 76th byte. Then when reading - after i read the map, pointer position always goes to 75th byte, yet that other data might start from 76th byte so in that moment I am not sure do i have to just start reading data or move on the next byte and then read.Maybe i don't understand smth.

Comment: You have to pass the archive, not the stream to your save function.

Comment: See also the bottom-most links in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28395831/85371): [Outputting more things than a Polymorphic Text Archive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422557/outputting-more-things-than-a-polymorphic-text-archive/27424381#27424381) and [Streams are not archives](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/)