# Reading binary file with batch size using boost serialization

Tags: c++, boost, binary, binaryfiles, serialization

I am trying to serialize the class with boost's binary serializer, and loading the binary data with batch size.

I am able to fetch the first 5 records out of 10, and the process is crashing while I am trying to read an another 5 records by re-opening the file and re-setting the file read pointer to the previous. I am pretty sure that, I am missing something here to re-set the file read pointer properly.

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::archive;
class logEntry {
 private:
    size_t m_txID;
    string m_jsonStr;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Archive>
    friend void serialize( Archive &ar, logEntry &l, const unsigned int version );

 public:
    logEntry() {
        m_txID = 0;
        m_jsonStr = "";
    }
    logEntry( size_t id, const string &val ) {
        m_txID = id;
        m_jsonStr = val;
    }
    string getJsonValue() {
        return m_jsonStr;
    }

    size_t getTxId() {
        return m_txID;
    }
};

template <typename Archive>
void serialize( Archive &ar, logEntry &l, const unsigned int version ) {
    ar &l.m_txID;
    ar &l.m_jsonStr;
}

size_t prevReadPos = 0;

void save() {
    ofstream        file{"/tmp/test.bin", ios::binary | ios::trunc};
    binary_oarchive oa{file};

    // Save 10 records
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        oa << logEntry( i, "{Some Json String}" );

    file.flush();
    file.close();
}

// Load data batch wise
void load( size_t bsize ) {
    ifstream        file{"/tmp/test.bin", ios::binary};
    binary_iarchive ia{file};

    // Record file length
    size_t fileEnd;
    size_t beg = file.tellg();

    file.seekg( 0, ios::end );
    fileEnd = file.tellg();

    // Reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file OR to the previous read position
    if ( prevReadPos == 0 )
        file.seekg( beg, ios::beg );
    else
        **  // THIS IS THE PLACE I AM RESTORING THE PREVIOUS READ POSITION, WHICH IS CAUSING THE PROCESS
            // TO CRASH.**
         file.seekg( prevReadPos, ios::beg );

    // Load records batch wise until we reach the end of the file
    logEntry l;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < bsize && file.tellg() < fileEnd; i++ ) {
        ia >> l;
    }
    prevReadPos = file.tellg();
    file.close();
}

int main() {
    save();
    while ( 1 ) {
        load( 5 );
        sleep( 5 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Boost Serialization wrong.

Archives are not "random access". They're complete storage formats with a header and (possibly) closing sequence.

If you create an archive to contain 10 records, you'll [have to] read that whole archive. Of course you can stop mid-way, because, you know, you didn't need to read the rest yet. But of course you can't expect to read the rest later, as if a whole new archive were starting at that point, because there isn't. The result is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

See also this about combining multiple archives into one file (you don't want to do that unless with a delineating format of your own):

- [Archives Are Not Streams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/serialization/doc/)
- [Outputting more things than a Polymorphic Text Archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422557/outputting-more-things-than-a-polymorphic-text-archive/27424381#27424381)